# cannot evaluate module 'react-native-maps' : Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, reactjs, maps, react-native

A problem occured while building application with 'react-native-maps'

here is my setting.gradle file

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
```

dependencies of android/app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.6.0'
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file updated with MapsPackage()

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new MapsPackage()
        );
    }
```

error which is coming:

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Cannot evaluate module react-native-maps : Configuration with name 'default' n
  >   ot found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.479 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

i have referred all the procedure mention in the given link https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

i have also seen https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/issues/288 but could not resolve the error

please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is in the dependecies in build.gradle file try with this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.6.0'
}
```

Deleting the line `compile project(':react-native-maps')` the problem is resolved. This line is created by `rnpm link` but is a bug.

In MainActivity.java should be like this:

```
package com.yourapp;   //<- put your app name
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage; //<- this line is important
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "yourapp"; //<- put your app name
  }
  @Override
  protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }
  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    new MainReactPackage(),
    new MapsPackage(this) //here you must be write the param this
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error `MainActivity.java:36: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override`  when I doing
    ^

Comment: @ubatin Removing `@Override` above `protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {` should do the trick

Comment: I solved by adding `import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;` `new MapsPackage()` in `MainApplication.java` not `MainActivity.java` (RN - 0.30 )

Comment: The first step was only needed for me but with the latest `react-native-maps` package so it was like: 
`compile 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.12.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after downgrading from **react-native-maps@0.7.1** to **react-native-maps@0.4.2**

I am using **react-native@0.29.0**

Here is my settings:

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
}
```

**android/settings.gradle**

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.package;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.AirMaps.AirPackage; // <- Add this line
import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new AirPackage(), // <- Add this line
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReactNativeI18n(),
          new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <!--reference your google_map_id-->
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_id"/>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following instructions from:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

I **noted** that `android/settings.gradle` should point to `react-native-maps/lib/android` as below:

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```