# React-Native can't run Android - react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, react-native

I have a `react-native` project and everything works great on `ios` but when I try to run it on `android` I get this error `':react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' > Could not find tools.jar`. I'm not sure what it means and I have done some research and found this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095524/cannot-evaluate-module-react-native-maps-configuration-with-name-default-n) However, it doesn't seem to be my case.

Does anyone know what this error means?

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-prompt-android')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android development requires to have the JDK installed on your computer. You have to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to a valid JDK. The error could be because you don't have a JDK on your computer. Try to Launch Android Studio and check that the JDK is here by creating an empty project, go to `File-> Project Structure` and look at the JDK location.

Comment: I didn't have the variable `JAVA_HOME` in my environment. Thanks! Will give bounty when time allows it.