# react native can't install react-native-maps (Android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I can't install react native react-native-maps, i get this error when i try to build with react-native run-android (I didn't try on iOS yet) :

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I followed the instructions here :

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

when i run :

```
react-native link
```

I get :

```
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-maps is already linked
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-geocoder is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-geocoder is already linked
```

It seams that it worked on iOS but not on android although for geocoder it worked (and the service is working fine).

So i follwed manual instructions and edited (but i still get the error above) :

> android/app/build.gradle
>   android/settings.gradle
>   MainApplication.java
>   android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (was already edited for geocoder).

I did play a bit with the version numbers in build.gradle :

```
// instructed in the installation guide -> build fail see above
compile project(':react-native-maps')
// Version 0.12.1 and earlier -> Build success but ERROR 500 in the app
compile 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.12.1'
// Version 0.12.2 and later -> error see below
```

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.12.2.

I've tryed different things but nothing worked. I tryed stuff from this link (but it seams deprecated) :

[cannot evaluate module 'react-native-maps' : Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095524/cannot-evaluate-module-react-native-maps-configuration-with-name-default-n)

Note : I'm on react-native 0.42.0

Comment: What version of React native are you using?  New versions of RN are not compatible with react-native-maps v12 for iOS and if I remember right, there may be a Java/Android incompatibility also.

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough I'm on react native 0.42.0 and i'm trying with android (didn't try with iOS yet). If new versions of RN are not compatible with react-native-maps v12 that would explain ERROR 500. Now how can i compile with latest version of react-native-maps ? - Note Question edited with precisions -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted an issue on git hub for react-native-maps project and got the solution [there](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1294?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container).

For those who have the same problem, the solution for me was that the instructions to change the android/settings.gradle are missing a /lib/

This gives :

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

If it's still not working you might try to remove the .babelrc from node_modules/react-native-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using react-native-maps v0.13.0 ? I'm also on RN42 and that version works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution to my problem and posted my own answer.